# android downloading apk file from internet results in parsing error

Tags: android

When I try to download file using the following code and run the apk file, it always results in "Parsing Error". I am clueless. Any help is appreciated.

```
try
                  {
                   URL url  = new URL("http://10.0.0.1/test.apk"); 
                         URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection(); 
                         conexion.connect();
                         int lenghtOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();
                         InputStream is=url.openStream();
                         FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream("/flash/test.apk");
                        byte data[]=new byte[1024];
                        int count=0;
                        long total=0;
                        int progress=0;

                        while ((count=is.read(data)) != -1) 
                         { 
                             total += count; 
                             int progress_temp = (int)total*100/lenghtOfFile; 
                             if(progress_temp%10 == 0 && progress != progress_temp){ 
                                 progress = progress_temp; 
                                 Log.v("APK Download", "total = "+progress);  
                                // Log.v
                             } 
                             fos.write(data, 0, count); 
                         } 

                         is.close(); 
                         fos.close(); 

                         Log.v("APK Download", "Download Done");  



                  }catch (Exception e){}
```

Comment: Please show the exact text of the stack trace, and point out which line it is referring to.

Comment: I see the trace in DDMS that as below:

Comment: netType:1 thisday:14944 uptime:193494 rxbytes:179291 txbytes:15580
12-01 23:46:32.503: INFO/zipro(1065): Could not find end-of-central-directory in Zip
12-01 23:46:32.503: DEBUG/asset(1065): failed to open Zip archive '/flash/test.apk'
12-01 23:46:32.538: WARN/PackageParser(1065): Unable to read AndroidManifest.xml of /flash/myfile.apk
12-01 23:46:32.538: WARN/PackageParser(1065): java.io.FileNotFoundException: AndroidManifest.xml
12-01 23:46:32.538: WARN/PackageParser(1065):     at android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlAssetNative(Native Method)

Comment: I guess the downloaded file is not getting stored properly, as you can see it says "Unable to read AndroidManifext.xml. Any ideas why it is not able to get the package properly?

Comment: Maybe completely beside the point, but I recently got the same error, when I tried to open an APK file (minSDK 8 for Froyo 2.2) but the actual phone had android 2.1 installed. It just reported me the parsing error, no further explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

God Bless! I was so confused and then I looked carefully the file which was uploaded on the webserver that was corrupt. If I upload it through FileZilla it's getting corrupted and if I use cpanel to upload the file, it works great. Thank you God, I am able to move forward in my coding after spending hours with this problem. :)